# how do I find examples of code with CVE vulns in it?

Tags: security, cve

Sup, everyone. I wanted to see how different CVE vulnerabilities look in real code examples. Not exploits, but vulnerable code. So, does anyone know if there is a site, git repo or anything with such stuff? Or i just have to search git for fixes of vulnerabilities and compare code like before/after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i'll post what i've found on the topic just in case. The original question resulted from my lack of knowledge about CVEs being an outcome of CWE exploitation. So, i should've been looking for code examples containing CWEs instead of CVEs. Hence, the web-site i was looking for is nist gov and their Test Suites.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit of vague question.

However, when it comes to WebApps OWASP is a great resources. They have a number of projects e.g. [WebGoat](https://owasp.org/www-project-webgoat/). This gives you both examples of insecure code and also tutorials around how to avoid the problems.

Of course, this doesn't necessarily include all recent CVE's, but is a great example of some real code examples.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a try)